# React router nested routes with exact path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-component

Please help. I'm trying to make nested routes but here is a problem: if I use `exact path`, I can't have nested routes.

For example, I want to have one route that is nested and one individual. I have to use `exact` if I want to have an individual one. How can I have both?

```
  <Route exact path="/projects" component={Projects} />

  <Route path="/projects/individual" component={ProjectsList} />
  <Route path="/projects/nested" component={ProjectsList} />
```

Here is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-night-fbjx6?file=/src/App.js:646-840).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, with an exact attribute you loose the flexibility to use nested routes. The solution here is to make use of `Switch` and order your routes such that the prefix paths are at the end

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/projects" component={Projects} />
  <Route path="/" component={Home} />
</Switch>
```

---

and inside Projects you can write the nested paths

```
<Route path="/projects/individual" component={ProjectsList} />
<Route path="/projects/nested" component={ProjectsList} />
```

Update:

If however on ProjectsList component i.e paths `"/projects/individual"` and `"/projects/nested"` you do not want to render Projects component you would use them like

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/projects/individual" component={ProjectsList} />
  <Route path="/projects/nested" component={ProjectsList} />
  <Route path="/projects" component={Projects} />
  <Route path="/" component={Home} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `/projects/individual` route will show without `Projects` component?

Comment: What do you mean it will show without Projects component?

Comment: I updated the code with another way which allows you to render `/projects/individual` and use `"/projects/nested"` and other paths seemlesly